# How to picture the number of $p$-permutations of $t$ things with $k$ kinds, where $n_1, n_2, n_3, \cdots , n_k$ = the number of each kind of thing?

Tags: combinatorics, visualization

Some students can't even grok [this problem statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2372), as they are [(informationally) overloaded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/311991)  by the number of variables : $p, t, k, n_1, \cdots, n_k \;$. Kindly improve [my picture](https://www.dreamstime.com/sorted-marbles-various-colors-white-wooden-sorting-box-child-s-hand-touching-picking-up-image123639958), or draw a better picture?

[image]

I match variables to the first letter of the mathematical object. E.g. $N$umber of each $\color{fuchsia}{k}$ind $= n_\color{fuchsia}{k}$.

Comment: I think the phrase "Pick $p$ permutations" is awkward and unclear. I would prefer something like "How many ways to make an ordered selection of $p$ objects?", or maybe "marbles" instead of "objects" to match the picture. Otherwise, the picture seems clear. Also, to make things simpler, you do not need to even mention $t$ (one fewer variable that way).

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks! Doesn't "permute" mean the same thing as "make an ordered selection"? And did I need to bring up $t$ things at all? Correspondingly, did the [linked original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) need $n$ objects? I am dazzled if both questions carelessly introduced a redundant variable!

Comment: Ok, but "Pick $p$ permutations" is still nonsense. Better phrasing would be "How many ways to permute $p$ marbles?". Or, "How many $p$-permutations of marbles?"

Comment: The reason you do not need $t$ is because $t=n_1+\dots+n_k$, so it is already determined by the other variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you are a typesetter manually placing [sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(typesetting)) – metal blocks containing raised mirrored characters on one face – into a line. You have $n_i$ sorts of character $i$, and $k$ different characters available, so $t=\sum_{i=1}^kn_i$. Then you want to count the number of $p$-character strings you can make with your limited resources.